# Angular Material 2: Having trouble displaying a newly created array within a function

Tags: arrays, angular, loops, typescript, angular-material2

I'm attempting to create a Barbell plate calculator where a user inputs the desired total weight and barbell weight and the app will display what weights they need on each side. It's still pretty barebones for now but I've encountered an issue where I'm a little stumped. Inside my "pounds" component I attempt to calculate the weight required on each side. Some of the Code with comments:

```
public barWeight: string = '45';
public totalWeight: string = '';
public weight: number = 0;

public plates= [      
  { weights: 100, id: 2, value: false},
  { weights: 45, id: 3, value: true},
  { weights: 35, id: 4, value: true},
  { weights: 25, id: 5, value: true},
  { weights: 10, id: 6, value: true},
  { weights: 5, id: 7, value: true},
  { weights: 2.5, id: 8, value: true},
  { weights: 1.25, id: 9, value: false},
];

// Filters out the plate array by value, 
// which in this case are checkboxes the user can toggle. 
get selectedPlates() {  
    return this.plates
        .filter(plate => plate.value)
}

public calc() {
    this.weight = ((parseFloat(this.totalWeight) - parseFloat(this.barWeight)) / 2);
    var totalUsed = []; 
    var idsUsed = [] ;
    var exp = 1; // just used to keep track of the count
    var platesUsed = [];
    //Beginning of calculation of weights on each side
    for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedPlates.length; i += 1) {
        let count = 0
        while (this.weight >= this.selectedPlates[i].weights) {
            this.weight -= this.selectedPlates[i].weights
            count += 1
        }
        if (count >= 1) {
            exp = count 
            totalUsed.push(this.selectedPlates[i].weights) 
            totalUsed.push(this.selectedPlates[i].id) 
        }
    }
    //loop that gets every other element of totalUsed array starting with the first element           
    // AKA just displays the ID's of the weights 
    for (let i = 0; i < totalUsed.length; i += 2) {
        idsUsed.push(totalUsed[i + 1]);
    }
    //loop that gets every other element of totalUsed array starting with the second element
    //AKA just displays the weights without their IDs
    for (let i = 0; i < totalUsed.length; i += 2) {
        platesUsed.push(totalUsed[i]);
    }
console.log(exp);
console.log(idsUsed);
console.log(platesUsed);
console.log(totalUsed); 
return {remaining: this.weight} 
 }  
}
```

Calc() is a click function meant to calculate the weights. It's probably pretty messy and incomplete but the problem here is that I can't display any created arrays that are within calc(). In this case, that would be idsUsed. I've assigned pictures of weightlifting plates by the id value. Though, they are just a public URL for now, I intend on changing that much later. I'm trying to display them in a grid list

Here's the relevant snippets of pounds.component.html

```
<md-card>
  <md-input-container>
    <input [(ngModel)]="barWeight" mdInput placeholder="Bar Weight" dividerColor="accent">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container>
    <input [(ngModel)]="totalWeight" mdInput placeholder="Total Weight" dividerColor="accent">
  </md-input-container>
  <button md-raised-button color="primary"  (click)="calc()">CALCULATE</button>
</md-card>

<md-card>
  <md-checkbox *ngFor="let plate of plates" 
  [(ngModel)]="plate.value">
    {{plate.weights}}
  </md-checkbox>
</md-card>

<md-card>
<md-card-content>
  <md-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="200px">
    <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let idUsed of idsUsed">
    <img src="http://www.roguefitness.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/o/rogue-calibrated-lb-steel-plates-web{{idUsed}}.jpg" layout-fill>
    </md-grid-tile>
  </md-grid-list>
</md-card-content>
```

Everything comes out blank. In the console log, I get the values I need, but I'm assuming that they are displaying because they're within calc(). If I move the variables outside of calc() the ngFor grid list will work, but the loops within calc() don't work properly, so the results are all over the place.

I'm not sure how to get idsUsed displaying properly. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: might be worth making a plunker out of your code so it's a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @chernabog_94 what is the reult of your console.log on console.log(platesUsed); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initiating `idsUsed` inside of `calc()` function because of which component view has no reference to it. I initialized `idsUsed` outside the `calc()` function and it started working.

Here's the plnkr [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/n3gayLGZ6H6pJ5uJ2mHw?p=preview) of your code, hope this is what you are looking for.

```
public barWeight: string = '45';
public totalWeight: string = '';
public weight: number = 0;

public idsUsed = []

public plates= [      
  { weights: 100, id: 2, value: false},
  { weights: 45, id: 3, value: true},
  { weights: 35, id: 4, value: true},
  { weights: 25, id: 5, value: true},
  { weights: 10, id: 6, value: true},
  { weights: 5, id: 7, value: true},
  { weights: 2.5, id: 8, value: true},
  { weights: 1.25, id: 9, value: false},
];

constructor() {

  }

// Filters out the plate array by value, 
// which in this case are checkboxes the user can toggle. 
get selectedPlates() {  
    return this.plates
        .filter(plate => plate.value)
}

public calc() {
    this.weight = ((parseFloat(this.totalWeight) - parseFloat(this.barWeight)) / 2);
    var totalUsed = [];
    this.idsUsed = [];
    var exp = 1; // just used to keep track of the count
    var platesUsed = [];
    //Beginning of calculation of weights on each side
    for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedPlates.length; i += 1) {
        let count = 0
        while (this.weight >= this.selectedPlates[i].weights) {
            this.weight -= this.selectedPlates[i].weights
            count += 1
        }
        if (count >= 1) {
            exp = count 
            totalUsed.push(this.selectedPlates[i].weights) 
            totalUsed.push(this.selectedPlates[i].id) 
        }
    }
    //loop that gets every other element of totalUsed array starting with the first element           
    // AKA just displays the ID's of the weights 
    for (let i = 0; i < totalUsed.length; i += 2) {
        this.idsUsed.push(totalUsed[i + 1]);
    }
    //loop that gets every other element of totalUsed array starting with the second element
    //AKA just displays the weights without their IDs
    for (let i = 0; i < totalUsed.length; i += 2) {
        platesUsed.push(totalUsed[i]);
    }
console.log(exp);
console.log(this.idsUsed);
console.log(platesUsed);
console.log(totalUsed); 
return {remaining: this.weight} 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the plnkr code.

I understand that initiating the idsUsed outside of calc() allows it to show the plates in the view, but it kind of messes up the calculation. 

For example, I entered 3 values for the program to calculate: 135, 155, 165. Here are the [console log results](https://puu.sh/wuQAv/b3c82123ac.png) which show the correct weights with their corresponding IDs. 

[This is the results of the same values in plunkr code you provided.](https://puu.sh/wuQqo/9db3a0a03b.png) The pictures of the plates seem to keep adding up on top of each other.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the calculation mess up, was focusing on getting images to populate. I'll work on fixing it in the demo and will let you know.

Comment: So, I added a line to reset the  idsUsed at the beginning of calc().  From my testing seemed like it matches with your results. Check the plnkr again, and let me know if this issue still persists, thank you!

Comment: Wow that did it. Thanks for taking your time with this.